# Userdefault Array Saving for Items on Plist Accordingly

Tags: swift, save, userdefaults

Okay so I just got a quick question if this is possible or not. I got a array of dictionaries on my plist and it shows on viewcontroller 1 in a list of cells about 800 items. If user hits one of these cells and goes to Viewcontroller 2 can I make like a array of userdefaults associated with each cell? For example if I have a list of fruits like Apple, Banana, Kiwi. User hits Apple and on the userdefaults it knows it hit the first cell and put a userdefault value of 1. What I am trying to do is give a userdefault value of each cell so that user can save these items to their favorite list and I just use userdefault to save that one specific item to favorite list. Cause currently when I use the userdefault it saves all the items at once because if I put the boolean to true for one item it does it for all items since each item on the plist cell uses the same userdefault key. Like on my viewcontroller 2 is set up

```
var isFavorite = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isFavorite")

@IBAction func addToFav(_ sender: UIButton){
    isFavorite = !isFavorite
    UserDefaults.standard.set(isFavorite, forKey: "isFavorite")
    UpdateButtonAppearance()
}

func UpdateButtonAppearance(){
    if isFavorite{
        let image = UIImage(named: "addFav")
        favButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    } else{
        let image = UIImage(named: "addFavFilled")
        favButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

So to avoid saving all the list the same way I was wondering how can I save each cell individually using the userdefault method?

Comment: User Defaults is probably not the right thing for yo here. It might be best to explore other caching alternatives. How long does this data need to be saved?

Comment: data has to be saved forever till user unfavs the item. Im just trying to add a favorite button where it just changes the value from false to true and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with keys for all of the favorites, such as "Apple", "Banana", "Kiwi", and "true" as the value. UserDefaults should happily save a dictionary for you if it understands both the keys and values, ie they are both strings.

```
let kFavoritesKey = "Favorites"
class FavoritesStorage {
    // Instantiate with some default favorites
    var dict = ["Apple":"true", "Banana":"true", "Kiwi":"true"]

    init() {
        loadFromDisk()
    }

    func favor(_ key: String) {
        dict[key] = "true"
        saveToDisk()
    }

    func unFavor(_ key: String) {
        dict[key] = nil
        saveToDisk()
    }

    func isFavored(_ key : String) -> Bool {
        return dict[key] != nil
    }

    func toggle(_ key: String) {
        let favored = isFavored(key)
        if favored {
            unFavor(key)
        } else {
            favor(key)
        }
    }

    // These can be changed to save/read somewhere else besides user defaults
    private func saveToDisk() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: kFavoritesKey)
    }

    private func loadFromDisk() {
        if let diskVersion = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kFavoritesKey) as? [String: String] {
            dict = diskVersion
        }
    }
}

let favorites = FavoritesStorage()

var isAppleFavorited = favorites.isFavored("Apple") // true
var isMangoFavorited = favorites.isFavored("Mango") // false

if !isMangoFavorited {
    favorites.favor("Mango")
}
isMangoFavorited = favorites.isFavored("Mango") // true
favorites.toggle("Apple")
isAppleFavorited = favorites.isFavored("Apple") // false

if let diskVersion = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: kFavoritesKey) {
    print(diskVersion)
}
```

Comment: Data has to be saved until user unfavs the item. Hey Randy so if I have over 800 items you want me to write var dict = ["etc": true....] for all 800 items? I cant somehow integrate my plist file that already has all 800 items change the boolean to true or false and save it?

Comment: @Dkeem You don't have to hard code any favorites, this is just an example solution. You can start with nothing favorited. Note that false is nil, so you don't have to save any items in favorites that aren't favorited. This is a simple, and compact, approach. Hope it helps.